# allocating flexible array members as a struct

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, flexible-array-member

I understand more about pointers and stuff but I have no idea what I am doing wrong here. 
if i Have 
    char *(*data)[]
That would just be interpreted as "a pointer to an array of char pointers", right?
Then I have a struct like this, typedef'd to be myStruct, redundant as it may be, but that's aside the point:

```
    typedef struct myStruct myStruct;
    struct myStruct{
      int size;
      char *name;
      myStruct *(*array)[];
}
```

Having looked around the site for similar posts, I got something like this:

```
    //let's say allocating 5 spaces for this case
    myStruct *a = malloc(sizeof(myStruct)+ sizeof(struct myStruct *)*5);
```

I am sure that the number I allocated the struct with is the size of the array. 
I can't quite get my head wrapped around this, how does it work if it's a struct? 
The plan here is to have this struct, and it contains an array of 5 myStruct's. Do I have to allocate them separately as well? like this?

```
    a->array[0] = malloc( .... )
```

I tried and it keeps giving me an error saying Invalid use of array with unspecified bounds. 
What am I doing wrong or how Can i fix this?
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

From your comment, it sounds like you want a pointer to an array of pointers to structures, rather than a pointer to an array of structures, since "pointer to an array of char *" also has two levels of indirection.

Here's the difference:

1. A pointer to a structure:
   [image]
2. A pointer to an array of structures:
   [image]
3. A pointer to an array of pointers to structures:
   [image]

Assuming you want #3, you can do it like so (in "traditional" C):

```
typedef struct myStruct myStruct;

struct myStruct
{
    int        size;
    char      *name;
    myStruct **array;
};

myStruct *allocate_node(char *name, int size)
{
    myStruct *p_node;
    if (size < 0)
        size = 0;
    p_node = calloc(1, sizeof(myStruct));
    p_node->name = name;
    p_node->size = size;
    p_node->array = calloc(1, size * sizeof(myStruct *));

    return p_node;
}

void expand_node_child_array(myStruct *p_node, int size_to_add)
{
    if (size_to_add < 1 || p_node == NULL)
        return;
    if (p_node->array == NULL)
    {
        p_node->size = size_to_add;
        p_node->array = calloc(1, size_to_add * sizeof(myStruct *));
    }
    else
    {
        p_node->array = realloc(p_node->array, (p_node->size + size_to_add) * sizeof(myStruct *));
        memset(p_node->array + p_node->size * sizeof(myStruct *), 0, size_to_add * sizeof(myStruct *));
        p_node->size += size_to_add;
    }
}

myStruct *get_child_node(myStruct *p_node, int index)
{
    if (index < 0 || index >= p_node->size)
        return 0;
    return p_node->array[index];
}

int set_child_node(myStruct *p_node, int index, myStruct *p_child)
{
    if (index < 0 || index >= p_node->size)
        return FALSE;
    p_node->array[index] = p_child;
    return TRUE;
}

void free_node(myStruct **pp_node)
{
    // Free p_node and the array but DO NOT free the children
    if (pp_node == NULL || *pp_node == NULL)
        return;
    if ((*pp_node)->array != NULL)
        free((*pp_node)->array);
    free((*pp_node));
    *pp_node = NULL;
}

void free_node_and_children(myStruct **pp_node)
{
    int iChild;

    if (pp_node == NULL || *pp_node == NULL)
        return;
    for (iChild = 0; iChild < (*pp_node)->size; iChild++)
    {
        myStruct *p_child = get_child_node((*pp_node), iChild);
        if (p_child != NULL)
            free_node_and_children(&p_child);
        set_child_node((*pp_node), iChild, NULL);
    }
    free_node(pp_node);
}
```

**Update**

A flexible array, under the C99 standard syntax, is a variable-length array that appears at the tail of a structure and whose actual length is set at run time.  It looks like this in memory:
[image]

Assuming your compiler supports this syntax (not all do), you declare it like this:

```
struct myStruct
{
    Type  array_of_type[]; /* AT THE END OF THE STRUCT ONLY */
};
```

And the code for "myStruct" becomes:

```
typedef struct myStruct myStruct;

struct myStruct
{
    int        size;
    char      *name;
    myStruct  *array[];
};

myStruct *allocate_node(char *name, int size)
{
    myStruct *p_node;
    if (size < 0)
        size = 0;
    p_node = calloc(1, sizeof(myStruct) + size * sizeof(myStruct *));
    p_node->name = name;
    p_node->size = size;

    return p_node;
}

myStruct *get_child_node(myStruct *p_node, int index)
{
    if (index < 0 || index >= p_node->size)
        return NULL;
    return p_node->array[index];
}

int set_child_node(myStruct *p_node, int index, myStruct *p_child)
{
    if (index < 0 || index >= p_node->size)
        return FALSE;
    p_node->array[index] = p_child;
    return TRUE;
}

void free_node(myStruct **pp_node)
{
    if (pp_node == NULL || *pp_node == NULL)
        return;
    free((*pp_node));
    *pp_node = NULL;
}

void free_node_and_children(myStruct **pp_node)
{
    int iChild;

    if (pp_node == NULL || *pp_node == NULL)
        return;
    for (iChild = 0; iChild < (*pp_node)->size; iChild++)
    {
        myStruct *p_child = get_child_node((*pp_node), iChild);
        if (p_child != NULL)
            free_node_and_children(&p_child);
        set_child_node((*pp_node), iChild, NULL);
    }
    free_node(pp_node);
}
```

If you compiler does not, see [here](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/void+MEMxx-C.+Understand+how+flexible+array+members+are+to+be+used) for some workarounds.

With flexible arrays, expanding the array would require re-allocating the node itself and fixing all references to it, something not required in the "pointer to array of pointers" design.

The syntax you are using:

```
    myStruct  *(*array)[];
```

should be [read as](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/reading-cdecl.html) "a pointer to  array(s) of unknown size of pointers to structures", rather than

```
    myStruct  **array;
```

which is "a pointer to pointer(s) to structures", or (e.g.):

```
    myStruct *(*array)[4];
```

which is "a pointer to array(s) of length 4 of pointers.

Your syntax actually produces memory map #3, however accessing the individual elements is a bit more awkward because you have to explicitly get a pointer to the zeroth element of the "array of unknown size", which is `(*p_node->array)`.  Thus the functions from #3 are modified as follows:

```
void expand_node_child_array(myStruct *p_node, int size_to_add)
{
    if (size_to_add < 1 || p_node == NULL)
        return;
    if (p_node->array == NULL)
    {
        p_node->size = size_to_add;
        p_node->array = calloc(1, size_to_add * sizeof(myStruct *));
    }
    else
    {
        p_node->array = realloc(p_node->array, (p_node->size + size_to_add) * sizeof(myStruct *));
        memset((*p_node->array) + p_node->size * sizeof(myStruct *), 0, size_to_add * sizeof(myStruct *));
        p_node->size += size_to_add;
    }
}

myStruct *get_child_node(myStruct *p_node, int index)
{
    if (index < 0 || index >= p_node->size)
        return NULL;
    return (*p_node->array)[index];
}

int set_child_node(myStruct *p_node, int index, myStruct *p_child)
{
    if (index < 0 || index >= p_node->size)
        return FALSE;
    (*p_node->array)[index] = p_child;
    return TRUE;
}
```

And finally, the test code for either architecture:

```
void dump_nodes_recursive(myStruct *p_node, int level)
{
    if (p_node == NULL)
    {
        printf("%*s", 4*level, " ");
        printf("NULL\n");
    }
    else
    {
        int iChild;
        printf("%*s", 4*level, " ");
        printf("Node: Name=\"%s\", array size=%d\n", p_node->name, p_node->size);
        for (iChild = 0; iChild < p_node->size; iChild++)
        {
            myStruct *p_child = get_child_node(p_node, iChild);
            printf("%*s", 4*level, " ");
            printf("Child [%d]:\n", iChild);
            dump_nodes_recursive(p_child, level+1);
        }
    }
}

void dump_nodes(myStruct *p_node)
{
    dump_nodes_recursive(p_node, 0);
}

void test_my_struct()
{
    myStruct *p_top = allocate_node("top", 4);
    myStruct *p_child0 = allocate_node("child0", 1);
    myStruct *p_child1 = allocate_node("child1", 5);
    myStruct *p_child2 = allocate_node("child2", 0);
    myStruct *p_child3 = allocate_node("child3", 0);
    myStruct *p_child00 = allocate_node("child00", 0);

    set_child_node(p_top, 0, p_child0);
    set_child_node(p_top, 1, p_child1);
    set_child_node(p_top, 2, p_child2);

    set_child_node(p_top, 3, p_child3);

    set_child_node(p_child0, 0, p_child00);

    dump_nodes(p_top);

    free_node_and_children(&p_top);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, From what I did I did have something similar to that. But, how would it change if it was *(*array)[] instead of **array? That is what I am confused about.

Comment: The cast in `(size_t)size` is redundant: `sizeof` gives a `size_t` so the other operand is promoted to `size_t` anyway. (If you're worried about `size` being negative then you'd need to add an explicit check for that).   And `malloc` followed by `memset` can be better expressed as `calloc`.

Comment: @user3314878 - are you trying to use flexible arrays from the [C99 standard](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html)?

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answers, I will try to fix my code with the tips here.

Answer (score 1):

`myStruct *(*array)[];` is not a flexible array member, since it's not an array type. It is a *pointer* which happens to be pointing to an incomplete array type.

The general pattern for flexible array member is:

```
struct myStruct {
    int size;
    char *name;
    Type array[];
};
```

where in your case, Type would be defined by `typedef MyStruct * Type;`. I'm assuming you want an array which will contain 5 pointers. (This is the same effect as having `myStruct *array[];` in the struct, of course).

(If you do actually want your struct to contain a single pointer, which points to an array of 5 elements; then flexible array member is not the right technique to use).

Your malloc is correct for this definition I have just given. It allocates a contiguous bloc of memory and you can use `array` as if it were actually an array of 5 objects, except you can't do `sizeof` on it to find the size.

Comment: yes, that's what I meant. If I already allocated the outside struct itself, I would assume that there is a pointer to an array of 5 myStructs inside? I can't seem to access these separately by saying a->array[0], it would give me an error. What is the correct way of doing it? I am confused, is the allocation making it so the array would have 5 elements? do I even have to allocate each of those 5 separately? If i do it gives me an error saying invalid use of array with unspecified bounds.

Comment: It's not possible to "allocate elements of an array separately", arrays are a contiguous bloc of memory. It's still not clear to me what you are trying to do. If you have already got memory allocated somewhere else then why don't you just point to it ? why are you allocating more memory?

Comment: Sorry, what I am trying to do is Have a myStruct node that contains an array of 5 myStruct nodes, sort of like a parent and 5 childs in a tree. The array being the pointer to an array of char*'s.
Having done the first allocation, I can't seem to access the array elements separately. If i say a->array[0] would give me an error about unspecified bounds. Maybe I am missing out on some basic trivial things, but I am really stuck.

Comment: Well, a struct can't contain itself (then it would have infinite size). And you need to distinguish between arrays and pointers.  Your error about unspecified bounds is because you have declared a *pointer to array with unspecified bounds* which is not a useful thing to do in this case.

Comment: "dbc"'s answer has some diagrams, do you want #2 or #3 ? None of those pictures is *flexible array member*. My suggestion in this code is like #3, except the struct and the table of five pointers is in a contiguous bloc, instead of being separated like in dbc's diagram.

Comment: ok, then let's forget about "flexible array members" for a second, and I'll have a look at that. I think #3 does match what i want? the *(*array)[]?  Or should I put it, How can I fix it in my case so it's not just a contiguous blocK?Or to make the unspecified bounds error go away?

Comment: If you want #3 then dbc has already posted the code to achieve that. You need to call `malloc` once for each separate block that appears in the diagram.