# How to properly allocate memory for nested structures?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, declaration

I'm trying to create a very simple blockchain for didactic purpose.
Each block contains variuos simple variables and struct variables.
The blockchain is a simple array of blocks.

```
#define BLOCKCHAIN_MAX_SIZE 1000

struct transaction{ 
    struct sockaddr_in sender_ip_port;
    int quantity;
    struct sockaddr_in receiver_ip_port;
    int randomNumber;
};

struct block { 
    int index;
    long timestamp;
    struct transaction transaction;
    int waitTime;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    struct block **blockchain = malloc(sizeof(struct block *) * BLOCKCHAIN_MAX_SIZE);
    blockchain[0]=malloc(sizeof(struct block));
    blockchain[0]->index = 0;
    blockchain[0]->waitTime= 0;
    blockchain[0]->timestamp = 1549035455; 
    blockchain[0]->transaction.quantity= 0;
    blockchain[0]->transaction.randomNumber= 0;

    struct block *newBlock= (struct block *)malloc(sizeof(struct block));
    //Fill up the new block with data

    blockchain[1]=malloc(sizeof(struct block));
    blockchain[1] = newBlock;
}
```

is this correct?

Thank you very much

Comment: Well, no. This is not correct. `blockchain[1]=malloc ...` allocates memory, then `blockchain[1] = newBlock` throws that memory away, creating a memory leak. BTW it is unnecessary and often counterproductive to cast the result of `malloc`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will ultimately depend on what you want your example for. This is quite an open-ended question and might get the attention of a close vote.

Your double-pointer on `struct block **blockchain` may be a good choice or not, depending on whether you want all the `blockchain[i]` data contiguous. If you use individual mallocs per each element, you may suffer from memory fragmentation.

As n.m. says, `blockchain[1] = malloc` followed by `blockchain[1] = newBlock` is definitely wrong. You want either the same strategy as with `blockchain[0]`, or just push stuff to `newBlock` and then `blockchain[1] = newBlock`: here you are just assigning pointers, not values.

Still, your "blockchain-like" structure can only hold a single transaction per block. Usually, you will want a variadic amount of transactions. Since in C arrays don't have an integrated length counter (they are just a contiguous space of memory), you would have to change your block definition to something along this:

```
struct block { 
    int index;
    long timestamp;
    int waitTime;
    int transactions_len;
    struct transaction transactions[];
};
```

This way, you can allocate a block of variadic length, that can have different lengths depending on the block. Related question: [allocating flexible array members as a struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26196919/allocating-flexible-array-members-as-a-struct)

This way your malloc call would also need to include length for the transactions, and would still be all allocated in a contiguous memory region.

I can't really comment on the sockaddr_in structs, since I don't know what you would use them for. Depending on their life cycle, you would want to store a copy of them (as you are doing) or just pointers to them, but it will depend on what you want to do with the data and whose responsability it is to modify/free/alter the data.